# Flexbox not working in safari with Next.js Images

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to lay out Next.js Images with `flex-wrap` with a fixed height but variable width depending on the image. I'm using tailwind.

I've got it working perfectly on Google Chrome like so.

[image]

However when I look on Safari it seems to be creating extra space around the image. How can I fix the Flex issue on Safari so it displays like Google Chrome?

[image]

Index.js

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 md:flex md:flex-1 md:flex-wrap md:flex-row">
    <div className="relative h-96 bg-red-100">  
        <div className="h-full ck-product-image-container">
            <Image className="_image" src="" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"  />  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="relative h-96 bg-red-100">  
        <div className="h-full ck-product-image-container">
            <Image className="_image" src="" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"  />  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="relative h-96 bg-red-100">  
        <div className="h-full ck-product-image-container">
            <Image className="_image" src="" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"  />  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="relative h-96 bg-red-100">  
        <div className="h-full ck-product-image-container">
            <Image className="_image" src="" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"  />  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="relative h-96 bg-red-100">  
        <div className="h-full ck-product-image-container">
            <Image className="_image" src="" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"  />  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="relative h-96 bg-red-100">  
        <div className="h-full ck-product-image-container">
            <Image className="_image" src="" layout="fill" objectFit="contain"  />  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS is mostly handled in tailwind however i've had to write some to target Next.js Image property.

app.css

```
.ck-product-image-container > span {
  position: static !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: intrinsic;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the actual compiled markup? You're sharing react code and it is not clear what CSS properties do the `layout="fill"` and `objectFit="contain"` adds (I can take a guess, but you should really show it in the question). There is also no `<span>` element in your markup but I suppose they are rendered by your `<Image>` component. See how to create an [mcve].

Comment: Adding a `autoprefixer` might solve your problem.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support#vendor-prefixes

Comment: You could try adding `flex-none` to each of your `<div>` tags having a red background.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure `postcss.config.js` is set up corroctly:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "tailwindcss",
    "postcss-nesting",
    "autoprefixer"
  ]
}
```

This is from tailwindcss documentation

> Since Tailwind does not automatically add vendor prefixes to the CSS
> it generates, we recommend installing autoprefixer to handle this for
> you like we've shown in the snippet above.

It might be because of using `gap`.

Safari recently added this feature, so if your browser is using old version, it might not work:

https://css-tricks.com/safari-14-1-adds-support-for-flexbox-gaps/

Answer (score -1):

`flexbox` are not supported in some browsers.
https://caniuse.com/?search=flex

One way of achieving it is prefixing with `-webkit-`

```css
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;

/*for others too*/
 display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
```

I recently found a plugin for doing the same thing

https://dev.to/philw_/a-small-tailwindcss-plugin-to-emulate-support-for-gap-in-older-safari-ios-browsers-1hld

Another but not sure way of achieving it is using.
I found it somewhere but not sure

```css
display: -webkit-inline-box;
```

About Flexbox usage in different browsers:

https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

If others didn't work try using autoprefixer

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support#vendor-prefixes